# gcd(a,b) is unique up to units in a unique factorization domain

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Im trying to prove that for some $a,b$ (not both zero) in a unique factorization domain then the gcd($a,b$) is of the form {$gu: u$ is a unit} where $g$=gcd($a,b$).

I'm looking for a hint. What I know is:

gcd($a,b$)= $g=ma+nb$ for some $m,n$ in my domain.

$g|a$ and $g|b$.

$a = a_1a_2\cdot\cdot\cdot a_n$ and $b=b_1b_2\cdot\cdot\cdot b_m$

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bézout's identity does not necessarily hold in a unique factorization domain.

In a general domain, a greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is defined to be *any* element $d$ such that

1. $d\mid a$ and $d\mid c$
2. for all $c$, if $c\mid a$ and $c\mid b$, then $c\mid d$

In a unique factorization domain a gcd of two elements is proved to exist (via the middle school rule), but in any domain we can prove that if a gcd of $a$ and $b$ exists, then it is determined up to invertible elements; more precisely

> if $d$ and $e$ are greatest common divisors of $a$ and $b$, then there exists an invertible element $u$ such that $e=du$.

*Proof.* By property 1 (applied to $e$), $e\mid a$ and $e\mid b$; by property 2 (applied to $d$), $e\mid d$. Similarly, $d\mid e$.

Hence $d=eu$ and $e=dv$, so $e=euv$ and either $e=0$ or $uv=1$. If $uv=1$, then $u$ is invertible; if $e=0$, we can take $u=1$.$\quad\square$

Answer (score 4):

Using the definition of gcd, if you take two of them, they divide each other, so are associate